# how to make a pop in and pop out animation

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a pop in and pop out animation, but for some reason nothing is working
Im taking inspiration from this site http://robinmastromarino.com/  (the loading elements screen)

```
const words = document.querySelectorAll('.word');
const current = document.querySelector('.current');
const next = current.nextElementSibling;

words[0].addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
    words[0].style.display = 'none';
});


/////
        <div class="words">
            <h1 class="projects word current">PROJECTS</h1>
            <h1 class="portfolio word">PORTFOLIO</h1>
            <h1 class="stuff word">STUFF?</h1>
            <h1 class="sections word">SECTIONS</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: you'll need some CSS to do that - did you forget the CSS?

Comment: This might be a useful resource for animations as well: https://animate.style/